# referencing a property inside object literal

Tags: javascript

I want to reference a `property's` value to another `property`, something like below.

```
var user = [
    {
       property : "some value",
       "name" : this.property 
    }    
];

console.log(user[0]);
```

The `name` property is coming as `undefined`. "name" is something `custom` i am giving to each property value to identify it.

Comment: can't do that because full object hasn't been created during compile time at the point you try to assign it so there is no `this.property`